# Disabling internet explorer cache for website development

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, kendo-ui, browser-cache

I am working on site's appearance (css, js modification kendo ui) but can't see the result on internet explorer because of cache. I tried shift + refresh but it doesn't work in some cases. how can i disable the cache temporarily or refresh the page in some way that I could see the changes? or is there any other issue with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several solutions:

- You may try opening the developer tools (F12), and in the Network tab click the "Always refresh from server" button in the toolbar, although I still notice some caching issues with CSS background-images
- Download and launch Fiddler, and in Rules > Performance, tick "Disable Caching" (I haven't tried it myself)
- If you have control on the sources, try to add a random parameter at the end of the URL (or a version number) in order to force the URL to change (eg: myfile.js?v=2)

Comment: Yes, but we have to open console then it will work and also in some case it doesn't work.